# How to debug boot process?

Tags: boot

After power outage my server (Ubuntu 16.04 ) wont boot, and I can't understand why it gives me "Give root password for maintenance" message.

I did `fsck` the root partition and it is being mouted in RW mode:

```
root@dev:~# cat /proc/mounts|grep ' / ' 
/dev/sda1 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount ro,data=ordered 0 0
root@dev:~# 
root@dev:~# touch /works
root@dev:~# rm /works
root@dev:~#
```

journal log doesn't give any clues:

```
 -- Unit plymouth-read-write.service has begun starting up.
oct 27 19:03:36 dev systemd[1]: Reached target Emergency Mode.
-- Subject: Unit emergency.target has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit emergency.target has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
oct 27 19:03:36 dev systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection.
-- Subject: Unit ureadahead-stop.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit ureadahead-stop.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
oct 27 19:03:36 dev systemd[1]: Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
oct 27 19:03:36 dev systemd[1]: Stopped Read required files in advance.
-- Subject: Unit ureadahead.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit ureadahead.service has finished shutting down.
oct 27 19:03:36 dev systemd[1]: Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
-- Subject: Unit plymouth-read-write.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plymouth-read-write.service has finished starting up.
--
```

I can setup ethernet interface manually and start SSH daemon, I can login and everything seems fine, except that it gets stuck in the `init` phase.

Given that everything is all right, how do I find out what is causing the maintenance prompt to show up? Where is the init script located and how to enable it to print debug messages or be more verbose?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, so I will post the answer for people who might get into the same.

I had a /volume in /etc/fstab , but this /volume was later replaced with a `bcache` filesystem and I never rebooted since then. Now, after unclean shutdown, when I rebooted, `bcache` locked this partition for its use, and the init process couldn't mount it at the /volume mount point. I commented this partition in /etc/fstab and that was it.

To find this error I had to boot into text mode  (by removing "splash, quite" attributes in `/etc/defaults/grub`), because in graphics I didn't see anything.